# `Error: Unexpected NAMELIST statement` in GNUFortran

Tags: fortran, codeblocks

The following script creates a derived type then attempts to output its namelist to a textfile:

```
program test
    implicit none
    character(len=:), allocatable :: CurrentString
    integer :: linelength, IO

    type SubjectType
            character(20) :: genre
            character(20) :: maindude
    end type SubjectType

    type BookType
            character(20) :: title
            character(20) :: author
            type(SubjectType) :: subject
            integer, dimension(2,2):: array
            integer :: BookID

    end type Booktype

    type(Booktype) :: Book

    Book%title = "Harry Potter"
    Book%author = "JK Rowling"
    Book%subject%genre = "Fantasy"
    Book%subject%maindude = "Ron Weasley"
    Book%array = RESHAPE([1,2,3,4],[2,2])
    Book%BookID = 105
    open(10, file = 'namelist.txt')

    namelist /mynamelist/ Book
    write(10, nml = mynamelist)
    close(10, status = 'keep')
end program test
```

When compiled however it throws an error:

> ||=== Build: Debug in Hello (compiler: GNU Fortran Compiler) ===|
>
> D:\TEMP\Hello\main.f95|30|Error: Unexpected NAMELIST statement  |
>
> D:\TEMP\Hello\main.f95|31|Error: Symbol 'mynamelist'  must be a
>
> NAMELIST group name| ||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0
>
> minute(s), 2 second(s)) ===|

A [google search](https://www.google.nl/search?q=symbol%20%22must%20be%20a%20name%20list%20group%20name%22&oq=sym&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0j69i61j69i59j69i60j69i65.2255j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#safe=active&q=symbol%20%22must%20be%20a%20namelist%20group%20name%22) really is not very helpful. The only forums I found go into why this happens, but not how to fix it. How can I get this to run in GFortran? Please note this does work in IFort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NAMELIST is a declaration statement. It cannot be placed between executable statements. It can only be used at the beginning of each unit before the first executable statement.

```
 type(Booktype) :: Book

 namelist /mynamelist/ Book

 Book%title = "Harry Potter"

 ...

 open(10, file = 'namelist.txt')
 write(10, nml = mynamelist)
 close(10, status = 'keep')
```